# ios: Index out of bounds error on non empty array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, indexof

For some reason despite all the checks, this loop is giving me an index out of bounds error on an empty array message. I know that the index is not out of bounds because I set up if statements to check for that, yet it still crashes. Also, when I edit the code to have an explicit index, for example array[0]....the app does not crash, which wouldn't make sense if the array is empty. Any ideas what could be causing this?

As for why I used a while and not a for to loop through the array, the for caused the same issue so I wanted to do the index myself explicitly and it still crashes the app.

```
  while(index < self.representatives.count - 1){
        if(self.representatives.count > 0){
             self.api.getPoliticianContactInfo(self.representatives[8].candidateId!, completion: { (result, id) in
                   print(result[0].value
                   print(id)
                   print("The index is: \(index)")
                   self.representatives[index].contactInfo = result  
                   self.api.getPoliticianPhoto(id, completion: { (image) in
                        self.representatives[index].photo = image
                        print(self.representatives[index].photo)
             })
         }
         index+=1
   }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code *in the actual question*

Comment: Does the array have more than 8 elements for this `self.representives[8]` not to crash?

Comment: It has 9 elements, so putting 8 does not make it crash.

Comment: You do understand, do you not, that your while loop runs repeatedly and finishes, and _then_ the completion handler starts running for the first time?

Comment: Yes, having asynchronous operations in a loop that is trying to process the array is a recipe for disaster

Comment: Oh so im fundamentally doing it wrong, didn't know that.  Okay, how should I restructure it guys? I need to loop through the array to get the photo urls.

Comment: 1. Does `representatives` have more than 9 items? Your routine is passing `representatives[8]` everytime, and if you had less than 9 entries, you'll get an "out of bounds" condition. 2. In your `if` statement, you should have a local variable that captures the current value of `index`. As it is, `index` may well have changed by the time that completion handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

Let's keep in mind the order in which events are happening. Here's the structure of the code:

```
while(index < self.representatives.count - 1){ // (1)
    if(self.representatives.count > 0){
         self.api.getPoliticianContactInfo(self.representatives[8].candidateId!, completion: { (result, id) in
             // completion handler // (3)
         })
     }
     index+=1 // (2)
}
```

I've numbered the key stages. So the loop runs: my numbers are 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2... until the index reaches the top limit. Then, and only then, we start going 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 for each of those passes through the loop.

That is because 3 is a *completion handler* in an asynchronous API. It is delayed; the rest of the code does not wait for it, but rather the rest of the code executes instantly and then, when things are ready, the completion handler comes into play.

It is very likely that this is causing your assumptions about what `index` is, and what order things are happening in, and even which iteration of the completion handler is happening in what order, to be incorrect.

Comment: Should I run the code on the main thread then? I feel like thats not the right move but I'm out of ideas. Thanks for responding by the way.

Comment: @BobFlanders - Have a local variable inside that `if` statement, which is the then-current value of `index`. And then use that new local variable inside your completion handlers.

Comment: You certainly should not block while the asynchronous code runs; that's the exact opposite of what to do. In my opinion, you shouldn't construct the code like this at all. You can't just loop simply when you have an asynchronous action to perform. You could start the next procedure as the final step of the inmost completion handler. You could line up some NSOperations. You could do something that doesn't depend on looping.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use indexes in this scenario and the fact that your code executes asynchronously and you have made assumptions about the size of the array doesn't help either.

You can use enumeration on your `representatives` array:

```
for representative in self.representatives {
    if let candidateId = representative.candidateId {
        self.api.getPoliticianContactInfo(candidateId, completion: { (result, id) in
            if !result.isEmpty {
               print(result[0].value)
               print(id)
               representive.contactInfo = result  
               self.api.getPoliticianPhoto(id, completion: { (image) in
                    representative.photo = image
                    print(representatives.photo)
               })
            }
       })
    }
}
```

Note that the network operations will still execute asynchronously, so after the loop has finished your `representatives` array won't be immediately updated with the data you are fetching.

If you need to execute some code when the network operations are complete then you can use a `dispatch_group`.